# Fetched results controller sectionIndexTitle based on transient attributes

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data

I have a core data entity 'Person'. I need to customise the section index title and so I thought of creating transient attribute the separate the data into some specific section based on my own logic. But, while I create the fetch request with fetchedResultsController, and keep this transient attribute 'sectionNameKeyPath' to initialize the fetchedResultsController sectionNameKeyPath. And so, I had to make this as a key to first sort descriptor. But, this crashes the applications. Isn't it possible to use transient attributes as sectionNameKeyPath in fetchedResultsController

My crash log is.

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'keypath sectionNameKeyPath not found in entity <NSSQLEntity Person id=1>'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a transient attribute as `sectionNameKeyPath` for a fetched results controller. But you cannot use a transient attribute in the sort descriptor. For a SQLite based Core Data store, only non-transient attributes can be used in sort descriptors.

This is documented in [Fetch Predicates and Sort Descriptors](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdPersistentStores.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002875-SW11) in the "Core Data Programming Guide":

> The SQL store, on the other hand, compiles the predicate and sort
>   descriptors to SQL and evaluates the result in the database itself.
>   This is done primarily for performance, but it means that evaluation
>   happens in a non-Cocoa environment, and so sort descriptors (or
>   predicates) that rely on Cocoa cannot work. The supported sort
>   selectors are ...
>   **In addition you cannot sort on transient properties using the SQLite store.**

But the first sort descriptor need not be the same as the sectionNameKeyPath, see the documentation of [initWithFetchRequest:managedObjectContext:sectionNameKeyPath:cacheName:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFetchedResultsController/initWithFetchRequest%3amanagedObjectContext%3asectionNameKeyPath%3acacheName%3a)

> *sectionNameKeyPath*
>   ...
>   If this key path is not the same as that specified by the
>   first sort descriptor in fetchRequest, they must generate the same
>   relative orderings. For example, the first sort descriptor in
>   fetchRequest might specify the key for a persistent property;
>   sectionNameKeyPath might specify a key for a transient property
>   derived from the persistent property.

The [DateSectionTitles](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/DateSectionTitles/Introduction/Intro.html) sample code from the iOS Developer Library demonstrates how this works.